# How do you do Multiple Inner Joins in Linq to Entities

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities

I have already searched through SO and could not fins a workable solution for this. I am just trying to figure what is the syntax for multiple inner joins in Linq to Entities. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jon's answer will work, but IMHO [using join in LINQ to Entities is usually wrong](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/), because it duplicates code in your model. I can rewrite Jon's query in a much simpler way in L2E:

```
var query = from customer in db.Customers
            from order in customer.Orders
            from product in order.Products
            from info in product.Info
            select new
            {
                customer.Name, 
                info.BriefDescription
            }
```

That's about 50% of the typing and 0% of the duplicated code. Consider that your relationships have already been defined in your DB and in your model. Do you really want to duplicate them again in every query you write, and break your queries when you refactor your model?

Comment: @Craig - I wish I'd understood what I was looking at here a couple hours ago.  What I missed was the "from order in customer.Order" - I was doing the equivalent to "from order in db.Orders", which is totally different.  Thanks for this, though.

Comment: This is CROSS JOIN which is not effective.

Comment: @TuyenNguyen: No it is not a cross join. It's an inner join. Don't believe me? Look at the result set for yourself. This presumes, of course, that you have proper FKs in your DB and model. All bets are off if you don't.

Comment: @CraigStuntz I am no expert but I think it produced a `CROSS JOIN`. Check out my same problem solved by @GertArnold http://stackoverflow.com/a/23349670/1565402

Comment: @Md.Ibrahim: GertArnold's solution is the same as mine here.

Comment: I have proper FKs in my DB and model and this does a cross-join using SQL 2014. Jon Skeet's query works properly for me.

Answer (score 8):

Well, I don't know LINQ to Entities particularly, but the normal LINQ syntax would be:

```
var query = from customer in db.Customers
            join order in db.Orders on customer.ID equals order.ID
            join product in db.Products on order.ProductID equals product.ID
            join info in db.Info on product.InfoID equals info.ID
            select new { customer.Name, info.BriefDescription };
```

(i.e. just several `join` clauses).

Now I suspect that you've already tried that - if so, what went wrong?

Comment: While this does indeed work, I believe it's better form to use relationships instead of joins in the specific case of L2E.

Comment: What about the case when we start with a couple of given Info-entities (`from info in db.Info where info... join product...`), wouldn't the explicitly written joins be more efficient in that case? Or doesn't it matter in EF and would `from customer in db.Customers from order in customer.Orders from product in order.Products from info in product.Info where info...` be just as efficient?

Comment: @j00hi: You'd have to look at the SQL being generated, basically.