# LINQ To Entities Multiselect

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Please advise,, ALL the resources I've perused , books, videos tutorials none have what I would assume to be a simple, common scenario.

-----What is the Most efficient and standard way of querying through bridge tables with Link To Entities-----

I'm trying to to a query  with Linq To Entities.I is my understanding that LinqToSQL is deprecated even if informally..

I have a standard
one to many (bridge table)
and the bridge table many to one for the final table 
and lastly a specific key for the original table
If it helps there's a User table atop this mess with a one to many user to roles

Tables:
  User, ( Not in the Query I have a specific KeyId for this table for the where clause),

Role,
&
  RolePermission, ( Bridge / map whatever you want to call it, it has FK's for Role & Permission )
                     [unfortunately it has other cols or this wouldn't be so stressful. I.E. its not 
                     abstracted in the entity framework its actually present],
  & Permission.

Summary I want every permission for every role for this user, User ID lets say 5
I have a list of roles per user so (to start) I intended on feeding this query the role ID and calling it multiple times ,,, appending its results to a list 4Ea RoleId  This is assuredly not ideal
Ideal would be to utilize the UserID & RoleID in a single query...

[How do you do Multiple Inner Joins in Linq to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442967/how-do-you-do-multiple-inner-joins-in-linq-to-entities)

This link above claimed that you can just pull his off by requesting all the tables involved without specifically joining them the PK-FK fields  ?!?!?!  Say What ??!

This is Just Peuedo code folks I've typed up several dozen attempts at this scenario

parameter p_RoleId  --- potential version of this could get RoleId's per passed in UserID ideally

```
List<Permissions> listToReturn = new List<Permissions>();

var result=(from p in context.Permissions 
            from rp in m.RolePermissions
            where m.roleID = p_RoleId            
listToReturn result.ToList();
```

I really just want to know how to correctly hook these tables together and specify some where clause.
Two table examples are everywhere.. but there or four  when you have a bridge table I found nothing

Comment: yes this may do nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var result = (from p in context.Permissions
                      join px in m.RolePermissions on p.roleID equals px.roleID
                      select p);
```

Comment: @ChristianProgrammer that doesn't mean anything, sometimes they vote down because that's their habit. So don't mind/care too much about that.

Comment: Thanks Folks   These helped

Answer (score 1):

Well you can definitely do what you are writing in your pseudo code. After all what you do is an implied join. But it might not be very efficient.

You are essentially doing a

```
select <something> from Permissions , RolePermissions where permissions.id = permissionsRoles.id;
```

And you do not need a foreign key for that. However in your case you have many to many

```
//with the assumption that you have a 
//navigation property between roles and rolepermissions in your model
var result = connection.Permissions 
                          .Where(i => i.Id == RolePermissionsid)that 
                          .SelectMany(i => i.RolePermissions).ToList();
```

Comment: What's this stray `that` in there?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
var result=(from p in context.Permissions 
            join rp in m.RolePermissions on p.RoleId equals rp.RoleId
            select p)
```

Comment: dude seriously thats what Henry Tshobo  suggested above ...  Im good now everyone thanks really