# pull all data with customer id

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I could not get the linq query to retrieve information from different tables and return it as a list.

For example customer id >> 5, I can write the code in mssql:

```
SELECT *
FROM        crm_customer_authorized AS AUTHORIZEDs
INNER JOIN  crm_authorized_describing AS authorized ON AUTHORIZEDs.authorizedId=authorized.authorizedId
INNER JOIN  crm_customer_describing AS customer ON customer.customerid = AUTHORIZEDs.customerid
INNER JOIN  crm_address_describing AS adress ON adress.customerid = customer.customerid
INNER JOIN  crm_customer_sector AS SEKTORS ON sektors.customerid = customer.customerid
INNER JOIN  crm_sector_describing AS sektor ON sektor.sektorid = sektors.sektorid
INNER JOIN  crm_customer_departman AS departments ON departments.customerid = customer.customerid
INNER JOIN  crm_branch_describing AS department ON department.departmentId= departments.departmentsId
INNER JOIN  address_codes_province AS province ON addresss.provinceid = province.addresscodeid
INNER JOIN  address_codes_provincece AS provincece ON addresss.provinceceid= provincece.section_code
LEFT JOIN   crm_position_describing AS POSITION ON authorized .positionId = position.positionid
```

output: 
[Result](https://ibb.co/bOWTc6)

How can I write this query with linq?

A customer has more than one address, responsible person.
A responsible person, a customer may be in the same sector, but the authorities are different.

I do not know the code of how to list more than one different information of a customer

I got the customerIds from the customer table

```
var customerIds = from cus in db.customerDescribing 
                  select new { cus.customerId };
```

I was then synchronize the customer s in the address table

```
foreach (var item in customerIds )
{
    var linq2 = (from address in db.addressDescribing.Where(x => x.customerId== item.customerId)
                 select new
                 {
                     Address = address.content,
                     CustomerId= address.customerId
                 }).ToArray();

}
```

but I do not know how to keep synchronizing with other tables

Comment: First,  you must create relation between these classes  with fluent API or attribute . so you have few relational between each other. then you can use query syntax or method syntax to loads. finally you can study about linq in online pages that teach about linq expressions.

Comment: @DragandDrop I had trouble loading pictures so I uploaded it to a different site. you will understand what I mean if you look at the picture.. thank you for your interest

Comment: @AminSaadati selamınaleyküm. I looked as you said, but because I could not do it, I asked for help from here. I do not write here without research. thank you for your interest.

Comment: I can see if I can edit
I  wrote an example but the continuation did not come..

Comment: @IbrahimALPSOY salam dear ;) ibrahim , please see this link , i think it's  a solution for you . 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442967/how-do-you-do-multiple-inner-joins-in-linq-to-entities'

Comment: @IbrahimALPSOY when you want use a multi tables that are connected , it's better you don't use where keyword and use join or in.

Comment: Btw don't mix both query and lamba in the same querry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you do Multiple Inner Joins in Linq to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442967/how-do-you-do-multiple-inner-joins-in-linq-to-entities)

Comment: I see no more activity on your question. As it a duplicate I will clear my question and comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are not using LINQ to Entities but just LINQ to SQL,

For translating SQL to LINQ,

1. Translate subselects as separate variables
2. Translate each clause in LINQ clause order, leaving monadic operators (`DISTINCT`, `TOP`, etc) as functions applied to the whole LINQ query.
3. Use table aliases as range variables. Use column aliases as anonymous type field names.
4. Use anonymous types (`new { }`) for multiple columns
5. Left Join is simulated by using a join variable and doing another `from` from the join variable followed by `.DefaultIfEmpty()`.
6. Replace `COALESCE` with the conditional operator and a null test.
7. `SELECT *` must be replaced with `select` range variable or for `join`s, an anonymous object containing all the range variables.
8. `SELECT flds` must be replaced with `select new { ... }` creating an anonymous object with all the desired fields or expressions.

Following this process on your query I get:

```
var ans = from AUTHORIZEDs in db.customerAuthorized
          join authorized in db.authorizedDescribing on AUTHORIZEDs.authorizedId equals authorized.authorizeId
          join customer in db.customerDescribing on AUTHORIZEDs.customerid equals customer.customerid
          join adress in db.addressDescribing on customer.customerid equals adress.customerid
          join SEKTORS in db.customerSector on customer.customerid equals SEKTORS.customerid
          join sektor in db.sectorDescribing on SEKTORS.sektorid equals sektor.sektorid
          join departments in db.customerDepartman on customer.customerid equals departments.customerid
          join department in db.branchDescribing on departments.departmentsId equals department.departmentId
          join province in db.addressCodesDrovince on adress.provinceid equals province.addresscodeid
          join provincece in db.addressCodesProvincece on adress.provinceceid equals provincece.section_code
          join POSITION in db.positionDescribing on authorized.positionId equals POSITION.positionid into POSITIONj
          from POSITION in POSITIONj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new { AUTHORIZEDs, authorized, customer, adress, SEKTORS, sektor, departments, department, province, provincece, POSITION };
```

Comment: Tahnks! that's what I want. then I will return the results with foreach and throw the corresponding DTO.